# Email service that will reply with emails after a certain amount of time

Tags: email, scheduled-tasks

Is there a service which I can send an email to, with the first words in the body as '2 weeks' or '13th may 2010' or 'in half an hour' and it will reply with an email in the specified time or at the specified date, ie in 2 weeks or on 13th may 2010 or in half an hour?

This would work great with gmail where the conversations are grouped, so I could forward an email to the service & I would get a reminder to do the thing in the original email at the time specified.

Am I living in a dream world?  Or is there some other service which would do this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any services that scan the first few words of your email like that, but there are plenty of great email reminder services like [Task.fm](http://task.fm/).

Comment: thanks.  that looks ok, but having tried it it doesn't seem to recognize my email actions, but will have a bit more of a play with it.  Not sure how it deals with other stuff in the body either.  but just the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: you say plenty?  any others you'd care to suggest?

Comment: Remember the milk ( https://www.rememberthemilk.com/ ), Later Gator ( https://latergator.ca/index.php ) , Ping Me ( http://gopingme.com/ ) , Email Remind ( http://www.emailremind.co.uk/ ) and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot.  task.fm seems to only send a preformatted reminder email, not including the original email.  I'll check some of the others out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a workaround but you could use [Remember the Milk](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/).

Remember the Milk allows you to [create tasks by sending an email](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/sending/emailinbox.rtm) and will [email you reminders when tasks are due](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/reminders/whenreminders.rtm).

So if you want an email in two days send Remember the Milk an email to create a task which is due in two days and it'll remind when it's due.